# Найти сумму элементов, больших 3 и меньших 8 и поместить ее в начало списка

Tags: c++, visual-c++, список

В следующем коде результат суммы помещается в конец списка. Как можно поместить результат суммы в начало списка?

```
List* Add_end(List* head, int index, int elm)
{
    List* p = new List;
    p->num = elm;
    p->nItem = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)  {
        head = p;
    }
    else  {
        List* current = head;
        for (int i = 0; (i < index - 1) && (current->nItem != NULL); i++) 
        {
            current = current->nItem;
        }
        if (index == 0)  
        {
            p->nItem = head;
            head = p;
        }
        else  {
            if (current->nItem != NULL)  {
                p->nItem = current->nItem;
            }
            current->nItem = p;
        }
    }

    return head;
}

int Sum(List* head)
{
    int sum = 0;
    List* p = head;
    while(p) {
        if ((p->num > 3) && (p->num < 8))
            sum += p->num;
        p = p->nItem;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это ваш код? Функция же обрабатывается эту ситуацию, для добавления в начало списка нужно вызвать:

```
Add_item(head, 0, sum); // где: head - голова списка
                        //    , sum  - значение
```

Answer (score 0):

Уж это проще всего :)

```
p->nItem = head;
head = p;
```